# display default time in cakephp ctp

Tags: cakephp, time, cakephp-2.0

i wish to display default time as 9:00 am in ctp time dropdown. Following is my ctp code:

```
<?php
                                      echo $this->Form->input('Rideoffer.DepartureTime', array(
                                                        'type' => 'time',

                                                         'interval' => 5
                                                         ));
                             ?>
```

how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'selected' option

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('Rideoffer.DepartureTime', array(
    'type' => 'time',
    'interval' => 5,
    'selected' => '09:00:00',
));
?>
```

Comment: isn't "default" the better option?

Comment: "selected" is usually not the best approach (it breaks the form after POST), "default" is in most cases correct (for checkboxes not) - please read the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#common-options

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set default data is using the controller (and only if not posted):

```
if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->request->data['Rideoffer']['DepartureTime'] = '09:00:00';
}
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#common-options

This works in all form elements.

"selected", "value", "checked" and other hardcoded attributes for the form directly usually break the form after an unsuccessful post (if the form contains validation errors): it loses all the entered data and reset them to the value it was before which is usually quite annoying for the frontend user.

see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/